# Initialize associated object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some trouble to fill my associated objects.

I have associated object, i try to fill my local DB's tables with form data, i can fill the building and all the object which composed itself : light_reseller, stage, furniture, location. But i don't find how to fill the component "points" of stage and 
furniture !

here is my model building.rb

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base 
has_many :stage, dependent: :destroy
has_many :furniture, dependent: :destroy
has_one :light_reseller, dependent: :destroy
has_one :location, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :light_reseller, :location, :stage, :furniture, :allow_destroy => true
end

class LightReseller < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :building
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :building
end

class Stage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :building
  has_many :points, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :points
end

class Furniture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :building
  has_many :points, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :points
end

class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :furniture
  belongs_to :stage
end
```

I use a form to fill my objects :

```
<%= form_for (@building) do |f| %>
<% if @building.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@building.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this store from being
        saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @building.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <h2>Store</h2>
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.fields_for :location do |loc| %>
      <%= loc.label :address %><br>
      <%= loc.text_field :address, class: "form-control" %>
      <%= loc.label :city %><br>
      <%= loc.text_field :city, class: "form-control" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.fields_for :light_reseller do |lr| %>
      <%= lr.label :"light_reseller name" %><br>
      <%= lr.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
  <% end %>
  <h2>Stage</h2>
  <%= f.fields_for :stage do |ft| %>
      <%= ft.label :name %><br>
      <%= ft.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
      <%= ft.fields_for :point do |pt| %>
          <%= pt.label :"point value" %><br>
          <%= pt.text_field :val, class: "form-control" %>
      <% end %>
      <h3>Stage entries</h3>
      <%= ft.fields_for :entrie do |et| %>
          <%= et.label :"entrie name" %><br>
          <%= et.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
          <%= et.fields_for :point do |ept| %>
              <%= ept.label :"point value" %><br>
              <%= ept.text_field :val, class: "form-control" %>
          <% end %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :furniture do |ft| %>
      <h2>Furniture</h2>
      <%= ft.label :name %><br>
      <%= ft.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
      <%= ft.fields_for :point do |pt| %>
          <%= pt.label :"point value" %><br>
          <%= pt.text_field :val, class: "form-control" %>
      <% end %>
      <%= ft.fields_for :point do |pt| %>
          <%= pt.label :"point value" %><br>
          <%= pt.text_field :val, class: "form-control" %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Add a Store", class: "btn btn-default"%>
</div>
<% end %>
```

and here is my controller :

```
class BuildingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_building, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @buildings = Building.all
  end

 def new
   @building = Building.new
   @building.build_location
   @building.build_light_reseller
   @building.furniture.new
   @building.stage.build
 end

 def show
 end

 def create
   @building = Building.new(buildings_params)
   respond_to do |format|
    if @building.save
      format.html { redirect_to @building, notice: 'building was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @building }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @building.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
   end
 end

 def update
  respond_to do |format|
   if @building.update(buildings_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @building, notice: 'building was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @buildings }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @buildings.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
   end
  end

  def destroy
  @building.destroy
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to buildings_path, notice: 'building was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
   end
  end

  private
   def set_building
     @building = Building.find(params[:id])
   end

   def buildings_params
     params.require(:building).permit(:name, location_attributes:[:address, :city], light_reseller_attributes:[:name], furniture_attributes:[:name, point_attributes:[:val]], stage_attributes:[:name, point_attributes:[:val]])
   end
```

So when i submit my form, my controller receive these data:

```
"building"=>{"name"=>"Fnac", "location_attributes"=>{"address"=>"12 bird road", "city"=>"Paris"}, "light_reseller_attributes"=>{"name"=>"Marc"}, "stage_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"First", "point"=>{"val"=>"1235"}}}, "furniture_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"shelf", "point"=>{"val"=>"45"}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a relation `has_many :points` with ***furniture*** and ***stage***, so you need to change

```
<%= ft.fields_for :point do |pt| %>
```

to

```
<%= ft.fields_for :points do |pt| %>
```

And also change `point_attributes` to `points_attributes` in your `buildings_params`.

Try the below changes too along with the above.

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :stages, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :furnitures, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :light_reseller, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :location, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :light_reseller, :location, :stages, :furnitures, :allow_destroy => true
end


def new
   @building = Building.new
   @building.build_location
   @building.build_light_reseller
   @building.furnitures.build
   @building.stages.build
 end

def buildings_params
   params.require(:building).permit(:name, location_attributes:[:address, :city], light_reseller_attributes:[:name], furnitures_attributes:[:name, points_attributes:[:val]], stages_attributes:[:name, points_attributes:[:val]])
end
```

`<%= f.fields_for :stage do |ft| %>` to `<%= f.fields_for :stages do |ft| %>`

and

`<%= f.fields_for :furniture do |ft| %>` to `<%= f.fields_for :furnitures do |ft| %>`

Comment: I tried to change what you said but my form's field for stage's point and furniture's point  are not print if i change to :

<%= ft.fields_for :points do |pt| %>

Do i need to initiate this field somewhere like i did for furniture :
@building.furniture.build